# How to resume the app with another page then the suspended?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I need to ask for a passcode every time the app was suspended (and resumed), so I have to show a corresponding page, and after the user enters the pin proceed the app resuming to the page which was shown before suspending. How can I get the page to which I have to proceed? The App.Resume event provides 2 parameters, but both of them are objects. To which type I need to cast these objects to get the proper page's type? Can I get from these parameters the proper page type at all?

I mean

```
private void OnResuming(object sender, object e)
{
    //get the suspended page's type here
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the following: 
In OnResuming simply Navigate to the passcode page, but remember the current page before. 
OnResuming should look like this:

```
    //...
    // the following line returns something like e.g. "MainPage"
    var pageTypeName = ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).SourcePageType.Name;
    // store pageTypeName in app scope
    // Navigate to passcode page ...
```

When passcode was entered correctly navigate to the previous page.

**Second Option:**
You can also try to navigate to the passcode page during "OnSuspending". The user will see the passcode page after a resume. After entering the code you can redirect the user to the previous page. Of course you also have to store the type of the current page during OnSuspending accordingly.

The code shown works fine if you have an "easy" interface without e.g. a SplitView. You probably have to tweak it a little if you are working with nested Frames etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was working on another project. I'm using the 1st option, it is working fine. After the user entered the passcode I remove the passcode view from the navigation stack, so the user can't navigate back to it (just a hint, if someone is implementing the same thing :) ).